# Every field homomorphism is injective or trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I feel like this problem should be fairly easily, however, abstract algebra is not my strength.

Let $k$ and $l$ be fields and let $\phi:k\rightarrow l$ be a field homomorphism. Prove that $\phi$ is either trivial or injective

Any hints on where to start would be great. Thanks

Comment: What Alex Wertheim said, plus more specifically, look at the kernel of $\phi$.

Comment: What? Every field homomorphism is just injective, full stop.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: some texts do not require that field homomorphisms map $1$ to $1$. (The 3rd edition of Dummit and Foote, for example, gives the exact statement in the title in Chapter 13, proposition 2, p. 512.) Of course, the proof is more or less the same, either way.

Comment: That's totally pointless, and it also messes up the geometry when you interpret fields as affine schemes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I don't disagree with you. I'm merely saying that the question makes sense under certain conventions. I agree that field (and ring) homomorphisms should take $1$ to $1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't get why this is a big sticking point. The ONLY difference between your definition and this definition is the inclusion of the $0$ map., which is what this exercise is showing. In some texts, they take field homomorphism to mean "nontrivial". Why is this an issue? I'm honestly asking.

Comment: @avid19: I mean, you could also put an extra number into the real numbers which you then proceed to do absolutely nothing with, but... why would you? Allowing the zero map between nonzero rings accomplishes nothing, and again, it doesn't match up with the geometry of affine schemes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: what are the ideals in a field?